# How to know wifi connection has internet enabled using windows apis

Tags: c, windows, wlanapi

I am using Windows XP. I am using wlanapi dll for getting API of wifi. When I connected with any wifi interface, How to know wifi connection has internet connection enabled or not? 
Is there any API or way to know??

Comment: 'internet connection' is imp.. very difficult to define because of the dynamic nature of the network of interconnected computers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try pinging a known server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050(v=vs.85).aspx

If not that I'm sure you could find something else in that library

Comment: Well.. there may be another route to such a server, over ethernet or 3G.